# Memory allocation for String in C++

Tags: c++, string

I tried the following code and it didn't work.

```
string tempStr;
tempStr[0] = 'a';
tempStr[1] = 'b';
tempStr[2] = 'c';
cout << "TempStr: " << tempStr << endl;
```

The output gave an empty string. Is that because, C++ has no way of know where my string ends. So it considers my string as a 0 length as found in the declaration.

If I try the following, I get "abc" as output.

```
string tempStr = "xyz";
tempStr[0] = 'a';
tempStr[1] = 'b';
tempStr[2] = 'c';
cout << "TempStr: " << tempStr << endl;
```

How can I get over the problem seen in first code?  Should I use vector of characters or something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *append* the characters. String isn't something that magically can allocate memory for you, so if you index it improperly, that is undefined behavior.

And yes, the string keeps track of its length and doesn't rely on nuls at the end.

```
string a = "abc";
a += '1';
```